# Why is there no $encoding parameter in htmlspecialchars_decode()?

Tags: php, character-encoding, htmlspecialchars

If we check out the [documentation of the `htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function in PHP, we see that it has an `$encoding` parameter to specify the encoding of the input string.

Now, conversely, I expect the opposite [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode) function to also have an `$encoding` parameter. However, this is **NOT the case**.

I want to know why exactly is this the case. There has to be some reason for not including an `$encoding` parameter in `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

Surprisingly, there is an `$encoding` parameter in [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), so what's the point of including it in that function.

Comment: Very interesting Question, I only can guess: I think it is, because you are able to set default encodings ``ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );`` and it is somewhat expected, that as long as you are "internalize" something you want it, in the format, which is defined as default... Just my guess so...

Comment: This is where PHP has its ambiguities :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to guess here slightly, but… `htmlspecialchars_decode` only decodes a small handful of characters which are all ASCII characters. So there's no need to specify the *target* encoding you want to decode these characters to, as they're all the same in all ASCII-compatible encodings. Now what if you wanted to decode to a non-ASCII compatible encoding? That is probably virtually never the case, and you can simply do some encoding conversion before and/or afterwards if you really needed that.

PHP has always assumed ASCII for the things that matter to it and arbitrary bytes for anything else that don't matter to it, so this function has never received any unified encoding support, just as a lot of other functions haven't either.

The functions `htmlspecialchars` and `html_entity_decode` have received this treatment at some point, as the cases where the encoding *does* matter are probably encountered more often with them. In the case of `html_entity_decode`, it decodes a wider range of characters and it does matter what encoding you decode those *to*.

`htmlspecialchars` appears to need to know the encoding to properly preserve the string's contents. I don't really understand why, as it would just need to look for certain ASCII bytes to replace, but *not* passing the correct encoding will garble your non-ASCII text.

Comment: I can relate to what you are saying, but the problem is that `htmlspecialchars()` does have it, and there's just no sense of it having the parameter.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` does seem to do… something… with strings besides just looking for the ASCII bytes of HTML special characters and encoding them. For example, `htmlspecialchars(iconv("UTF-8", "SJIS", "<漢字 &>"))` garbles the input when not passing "SJIS" as the `htmlspecialchars` `$encoding` parameter. I'm not entirely sure what it does, but here we are.

Comment: You're right. I also noticed that it does more than just look for ASCII bytes. But then I expect `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to do the same, what do you think?

Comment: Is there any way to ask this from the developers of PHP, maybe on GitHub?

Comment: I imagine digging through the C implementation to see what it does would be a good first step.

Comment: That often doesn't help :) I've tried it.

Comment: Upon looking into the source code, I've found that `htmlspecialchars_decode()` uses ISO-8859-1 by default, for performance.

Comment: But still, it's difficult to understand why is a charset used for `htmlspecialchars()`. Can you help me figure it out?